# How do you find the following limit as x approaches infinity?

Tags: limits, radicals

$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+9} - \sqrt{x^2-2}$

I have tried multiplying by the conjugate but the square roots are throwing me off and I'm not sure what to do next. How do you solve this?

Comment: What do you get after you multiply by the conjugate?

Comment: You should get $\frac{11}{(x^2+9)^{1/2}+(x^2-2)^{1/2}}$ after conjugating

Comment: Indeed I do get exactly what @illysial posted, except I left the root symbols.

Comment: Do you see what the denominator approaches?

Comment: Now it is clear that as $x$ gets big, the thing dies.

Comment: Ah, because it's still basically 11/infinity. Got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x^2+9}-\sqrt{x^2-2}=\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+9}-\sqrt{x^2-2})(\sqrt{x^2+9}+\sqrt{x^2-2})}{\sqrt{x^2+9}+\sqrt{x^2-2}}=\frac{x^2+9-x^2+2}{\sqrt{x^2+9}+\sqrt{x^2-2}}=\frac{11}{\sqrt{x^2+9}+\sqrt{x^2-2}}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2+9}-\sqrt{x^2-2}=\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{11}{\sqrt{x^2+9}+\sqrt{x^2-2}}=0$$